# count number of order every hour with loopback4

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, loopback4

Salem,
I have tried to return the number of order per hour, so i need to extract the hour in the property createdAt in my order Model that's why i think to use The getHours() method returns the hour for the specified date.
My method:

```js
 @get('/orders/count-perHour/{date}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Order model count',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: CountSchema } },
      },
    },
  })
  async countPerHour(
    @param.path.string('date') date: string): Promise<any> {
let dateStart=new Date(date) ;
dateStart.setSeconds(0);
dateStart.setMinutes(0);

let dateEnd=new Date(date) ;
dateEnd.setSeconds(59);
dateEnd.setMinutes(59);

    return await this.orderRepository.count(
      { 
        createdAt: {
          lte: dateEnd
          ,
          gte: dateStart
        }
 }
    );
  }
```

the property createdAt in mu model order:

```
@property({type: 'date',})createdAt?: string;
```

Error: it return false comparison, for example if i have one order at hour:10 it return 6

Comment: Are you trying to filter/count orders within a certain hour? i.e. if `hour=10`, all orders created at 10.00am in each day?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Salit.ha, i try to filter all orders according to an input ISO datetime and i compare this date between 2 others dates(dateStart) setSeconds setMinutes to 0 and (dateEnd) setSeconds setMinutes to 59.return await this.orderRepository.count( { createdAt:  lt: dateEnd  ,  gte: dateStart } but it return to me false comparison for exmple if i have only one order at 10 it return 6

Comment: Salitha i add the whole method as response. 
Can you please help me